# Flutter - Define last frame event when scrolling (swipe) in ListView.Builder (with state)

Tags: android, flutter

The question is when there is state management, i.e. in StatefulWidget.

There is a ListView.Builder that creates a list of 1,000 rows. Each line contains an icon and a Container with the text "index - N". I need that when shifting or scrolling (swipe), the text in the Container is written only on the last frame of the shift or scrolling (swipe) - not on the last line/entry in the list, but on the last frame (screen update) ListView.Builder.

How to find out the event of the last frame when shifting or scrolling (swipe) in ListView.Builder, so that it is on the last frame that the text is displayed in the Container?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 1000,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Row(
              children: [
                const Icon(Icons.list),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                  child: Text('  index - $index'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So what you want is only the part of your ListView that is visible on your screen should be loaded and the rest should not until it's scrolled to?

Comment: I want all scrolling frames (except the very last frame) to have everything - except for text. The text is shown only on the very last frame of the screen update.

Comment: Step by step.
Down finger -> finger movement -> Up finger -> several frames of scrolling the screen -> the last frame of scrolling. I need to show text only at the "last frame of scrolling" moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to get is the to hide the text when the scrolling event is happening and bringing back as soon as the scrolling ends, if that's what you are looking for then use `NotificationListener` to get updates about scrolling status, and then hide the `Text` widgets when the scrolling is underway

We will make use of `ScrollUpdateNotification` to detect when scrolling is underway and `ScrollEndNotification` to detect when it ends

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isScrolling = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
          if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
            _setScrolling(true);
          } else if (notification is ScrollEndNotification) {
            _setScrolling(false);
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: ListView.builder(),// the rest of your code
      ),
    );
  }

  void _setScrolling(bool isScrolling) {
    setState(() => _isScrolling = isScrolling);
  }
}
```

full code here: https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z54u06o554v0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

This is how it looks in practice :

[image: final result]

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want - you got it right. I tried your code and it works great (especially after I didn't improve it much). Thank you very much. Live long and happily. Good luck.